# Update query SQL Server with Excel data

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, oledb

I'm trying to update my SQL table with an excel file. 
When I try to use OLEDB, I get the error:

Server: Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

I was trying the folowing query:

```
UPDATE x
SET x.ShopName = y.ShopName
FROM dbo.StandInStore x INNER JOIN
(
SELECT [Stand_ID], [ShopName]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;Database=C:\Documents and             Settings\vdbergv\Desktop\test.xls;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')) y
ON x.stand_ID = y.stand_ID
```

I have read/write wrights, but I think the server isn't supporting OLEDB, I'm not the administrator so I can't reconfigure the server, like many solutions on the internet.

Any idea how to solve this problem or an alternative for OLEDB?

Regards

Comment: couldnt you import the xml first to a tempdb?

Comment: I haven't the wrights to create new tables

Comment: I have been getting the same error on one of my virtual machines I dont know what is the reason for it but I think it has something to do when 32bit office conflicts with your 64bit Sql Server version. You have to uninstal your 64bit driver and install 32bit to fix this. But I am really interested to see if you get a proper solution for this

Comment: Even with a 64bit office generated excel, I get the same problem.

Comment: I would suggest connecting to sql server while recording macro and capturing connectivity setup. I got something like this:  Dim cnt1 As ADODB.Connection////
Dim rst1 As ADODB.Recordset